# Change typo3 template with a language condition, how to write this?

Tags: conditional-statements, typo3, fluid-layout, typo3-12.x

I try to make a typo3 template condition that will change pert of the html template depending on the language.
I have three languages id: 0, 2 and 3.
I use:
Typo3 12.4.9
Bootstrap 14.0.7

I have tried this and similar variants, but don't really have a clue what I need to do.

```
<f:if condition="{siteLanguage.languageId}=={1}"> 
    <f:then>
        <div>language 1</div>
    </f:then>
    <f:if else>
        <div>language 2</div>
    </f:if else>
    <f:else>
        <div>default language</div>
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Please can someone help me solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you can check if the variable siteLanguage is available in your Fluid Template:

```html
<f:debug>{siteLanguage}</f:debug>
```

will output die siteLanguage object (if available, otherwise "null")

```html
<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>
```

will output all variables that are available so you can also see if siteLanguage is listed there.

Second, the condition should be

```html
<f:if condition="{siteLanguage.languageId}==1">
```

as you are comparing a variable with a number - the number must not be in curly brackets.

If you do not have the **siteLanguage** variable available in the **Fluid template**, you'll need to pass the **siteLanguage** to your **FLUIDTEMPLATE** TypoScript settings as a variable first, so that it becomes available in the Fluid template.
Here's how you can do this in TypoScript:

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {

  // ... your other FLUIDTEMPLATE settings ...
   
  variables {
    languageUid = TEXT
    languageUid.data = site:languageId
  }
}
```

Then, in your Fluid template, you can use languageUid to make conditional checks like so:

```html
<f:section name="Main">
  <f:if condition="{languageUid} == 0">
    <!-- Content for default language (id: 0) -->
  </f:if>
  <f:if condition="{languageUid} == 2">
    <!-- Content for second language (id: 2) -->
  </f:if>
  <f:if condition="{languageUid} == 3">
    <!-- Content for third language (id: 3) -->
  </f:if>
      
  <!-- Other content... -->
</f:section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your FLUID syntax is not correct.
As there is no `elseif` you need to cascade indvidual `if` conditions:

here an indention with related `f:if`, `f:then` and `f:else` on one level:

```
<f:if condition="{siteLanguage.languageId}==1"> 
<f:then>
    <div>language 1</div>
</f:then>
<f:else>
    <f:if condition="{siteLanguage.languageId}==2>
    <f:then>
        <div>language 2</div>
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        <div>default language</div>
    </f:else>
    </f:if>
</f:else>
</f:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Diferent markup for different values of a variable/placeholder**

As the question is on checking a variabe against multiple values and having dedicated content per value, with a fallback I'd suggest to switch to the `<f:switch />` conditional switch instead if if/if-else/then constructs. [[1] switch viewhelper](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/typo3fluid/fluid/latest/Switch.html)

```html
<f:switch expression="{siteLanguage.languageId}">
    <f:case value="0"><!-- Content for default language (id: 0) --></f:case>
    <f:case value="1"><!-- Content for second language (id: 1) --></f:case>
    <f:case value="3"><!-- Content for third language (id: 3) --></f:case>
    <f:defaultCase><!-- Default content for other languages --></f:defaultCase>
</f:switch>
```

**Site and SiteLanguage in Templates**

The `site` and `siteLanguage` are not available in a fluid template by default. So depending in which context / template you require this, there are different options available or options which needs to be used to provide it first:

- content elements with fluid templates (FLUIDTEMPLATE): Use the [[2] SiteProcessor](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/SiteProcessor.html) and [[3] SiteLanguageProcessor](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/SiteLanguageProcessor.html) to set them to the template
- ExtbasePlugins: Assign the site and siteLanguage as variable to the view
- Create a custom ViewHelper which registers the site/siteLanguage in the rendering context as variable (NOT returning it !!!!)

For an extbase plugin, you could add following to your controller action:

```php
public function detailAction(): ResponseInterface
{
   $request = $this->request;
   $site = $request->getAttribute('site');
   $siteLanguage = $request->getAttribute('language');
   $this->view()->$view->assignMultiple([
     'site' => $site,
     'siteLanguage' => $siteLanguage,
   ]);
}
```

Or with a custom ViewHelper:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyVendor\MyExt\ViewHelpers\Site;

use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContextInterface;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Traits\CompileWithRenderStatic;

class CustomViewHelper extends AbstractViewHelper
{
    use CompileWithRenderStatic;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $escapeOutput = false;

    /**
     * @param array $arguments
     * @param \Closure $renderChildrenClosure
     * @param RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function renderStatic(
        array $arguments,
        \Closure $renderChildrenClosure,
        RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext
    ) {
        $request = $renderingContext->getRequest()
          ?? $GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST']
          ?? null;
        if ($request instanceof ServerRequest) {
          $site = $request->getAttribute('site');
          $siteLanguage = $request->getAttribute('language');
          $variableContainer = $renderingContext
            ->getVariableContainer();
          $variableContainer->add('site', $site);
          $variableContainer->add('siteLanguage', $siteLanguage);
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

adding the viewhelper namespace to your template and simply calling it:

```html
<html
 xmlns:m="http://typo3.org/ns/MyVendor\MyExtension\ViewHelpers"
 data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true"
>
  <m:custom />
  <f:debug inline="1">{site}</f:debug>
  <f:debug inline="1">{siteLanguage}</f:debug>
</html>
```

- [[1] switch viewhelper: https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/typo3fluid/fluid/latest/Switch.html](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/typo3fluid/fluid/latest/Switch.html)
- [[2] SiteProcessor](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/SiteProcessor.html)
- [[3] SiteLanguageProcessor](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/SiteLanguageProcessor.html)